# Not able to compare two field values whether those are equal or not

Tags: formula

I am having 3 custom fields,

- activity closed week (Formula)
- iplan planned week (Number)
- iplan categorization (Formula)

I am trying to check whether  activity closed week is equal to iplan planned week, Using this  ----  `IF( Activity_Closed_Week__c   =  Planned_Week__c , "TRUE", "FALSE")`,
But here the problem is, it always giving false, either the values are same or not.

but if i am trying to compare using '<' or '>' , its working, the only thing that it is not working for is '=' or '<>'. 
Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: We don't have enough details to answer your question. What is the return type of Activity Closed Week and Planned Week? What type of values do they return? How many decimal places are you using? Do you use FLOOR or CEIL to make sure they're whole numbers? It's pretty easy to get false equal comparisons.

Comment: dude , return type is number, here is the formula field Activity Closed Week---Case( 
MOD( DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate), 1, 1) - DATE (1900, 1, 7), 7), 
0, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 3) /7, 
1, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 4) /7, 
2, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 5) /7, 
3, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 6) /7, 
4, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 7) /7, 
5, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 1) /7, 
6, ( ActivityDate- DATE(YEAR(ActivityDate),1,1) + 2) /7, 
99)

Comment: How many decimal places are you using in both Activity_Closed_Week__c and Planned_Week__c?

Comment: 0 (Zero) decimal places